# Model of sales of a new product

Tags: microeconomics, reference-request, consumer-theory, innovation

I am looking for any popular model to calculate sales of a new product under the assumption that some goodnesses of the product are given.

For example, the novelty $N$ and usefulness $U$ of a new product are given, the sales $S$ of it might be calculated as $S(N,U) = N^\alpha + U^\beta + c$ ($1 \leq \alpha, 1 \leq \beta$, and $c$ is a constant number).

I believe this model is too naive and a researcher proposed some popular model. But, I could not find it.

Comment: If possible, would you mind expanding a bit more on the specifics of what you were interested in? For example, besides the inclusion of a "novelty" and "usefulness" parameter, are there any other features you'd like the model to have? Is there any specific way you'd like these parameters defined? Is your interest primarily for a theory model, or an empirical work (where estimation is necessary)? Are there any specific fields you're interested in applying this model to (for example, industrial organization, firm decision making, etc.)?

Comment: @AndrewC Thank you for your comment! I am doing literature survey of previous studies that build a model of the revenue of a new product. So, any model about it is welcome. More specifically, my interest is in innovative products, so, the novelty of a new product is important attribute for me.